# How do you deal with longer right hand middle finger when playing classical guitar?

Tags: guitar, technique, classical-music

My right hand technique is quite poor, and middle finger keeps touching the string below.

Should I find the ideal amount of curvature of middle finger? Or is there another way?

Comment: If possible, add a picture. That often leads to specific suggestions.

Comment: As it stands, there's not enough information to give useful answers to this. i tried, but may be well off the mark. Please edit so we have a lot more to go on. String below?? Which one is that?, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Often, touching the string below (apoyando), is actually an oft used technique in classical guitar playing! Pluck the string concerned, upwards, and let the same finger come to rest on the lower pitched string next to it. Tirando is the other, where a string is plucked, and the plucking finger touches nothing else until it's deployed again.

Actually, a very quick Google found an absolute myriad of texts and videos on 'how to play classical guitar with the right hand', with many ideas available. Have a look!

As far as solutions are concerned, there could be many little things that make this happen. Angle(s) of guitar, how it's held when you play, curvature of fingers, position of hand over the strings, etc., etc.

A start point is to not anchor the hand either with the pinky on the body, or the thumb on the 6th string. Try to anchor it with the forearm on the body, so at least it doesn't wave around. Of course curl fingers at the same time, and this will even out their length differences somewhat.

In reality, I could write a book on what's possibly going wrong, and that's inappropriate here! Suffice to say - find a teacher, who will be able in a very short time (even one or two lessons) to rectify the problem - you maybe won't need more than that. But asking complete strangers with no pics/video and very little other information makes this impossible to answer to anyone's satisfaction!

Comment: This seems like a lot of words that don’t contain a real answer. And there are real answers to this. The only thing valuable here is “find a teacher” which imho goes in a comment, not in an answer. Oh and the part about not anchoring with the thumb is kinda wrong in many situations. Or at least isn’t not always right and in my experience poor advice to give to someone learning.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  - given the sparse information in the question, i was trying to be as helpful as I could. Yes, of course there are real answers to this. Whether they're actually relevant to OP is another matter. And, anchoring (or not) with the thumb - opinion. I'm trying, other answers please!

Comment: An alternate approach that wouldn’t get my downvote would be to wait until the question is clear to you before attempting to answer. Also this answer reads like it was written by someone who doesn’t know a lot about classical guitar technique, which further suggests just refraining from answering entirely. And there’s some points here that I’m pretty sure are simply wrong. So to me it’s more harmful than helpful. Anchoring is only an opinion as much as any refined and sound and universally used technique is. Maybe a few pros don’t do it but that’s no reason to say not to.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - seems you know a lot more, so  a superior answer is awaited.

Comment: Since they are talking about a longer middle finger I believe by “below” the OP means the string physically below, as in the higher string. Clarification should be provided by the asker.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - since plucking on classicals is usually towards the next string down in pitch (pluck string 3, end up touching string 4) my answer is based on that. But we know what assumptions do... Ah, I assumed finger touching the adjacent string *before* the proper pluck. Your assumption also?

Comment: @Tim since finger curvature was mentioned I just thought the issue might be touching the B string before the G because the middle finger is longer. As we know from experience we have to curve our fingers different amounts to make contact with a single string but this is a learned skill. As with a lot of first time posters, there has been no comment or clarification regarding their issue so far.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - the  middle finger often gets used to play the 2nd string, (no, not always, sometimes!) so that throws even more confusion! Now, I vtc until better info. is forthcoming.

Comment: @Tim I actually meant to say the B might get touched inadvertently when trying to play the G string.